# Azure Logic App is only inserting 100 rows into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, azure-logic-apps

I'm having a List in my SharePoint Online which is having 652 rows.

My aim is to insert these 652 rows into On prem SQL Server table.

I've a task Get items, followed by a For each and Insert row (V2) inside the For each.

In the For each settings I've switched on the Concurrency Control & the Degree of Parallelism is set to 50.

Every time I execute the logic app, I see that the execution is successful, but only 100 rows gets inserted into the SQL server table.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it in my side, it seems the problem was not related to "**For each**" Concurrency Control & the Degree of Parallelism. The reason for this problem is the "**Get items**" action of SharePoint connector can just get 100 records in default from the list.

To solve this problem, you just need to set the the parameter "**Top Count**" to `999`.
[image]

**By the way:**

I guess the "**Get items**" action request the [microsoft graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in the backend to get items. And the graph api response 100 records by default, so it just get 100 records in your logic app (if you didn't set "**Top Count**" parameter). And we can know from the microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#top-parameter), the `$top` parameter just support a maximum value of 999. So I guess the "**Get items**" action in logic app can also support a maximum value of 999(I'm not sure).
[image]

Comment: Thanks Hury, I also found the Concurrency problem a couple of days ago & I've solved the issue. Can you let me know how to increase the run session time, because I'm experiencing session time out.

Comment: Hi @AritraSarkar What do you mean of run session time ? Do you mean the logic app shows time out ?

Comment: Yes @HuryShen The logic app shows time out. Actually, I was trying to fetch 652 records from SharePoint and using a for each loop insert them into SQL server. So, it takes 2 minutes & above to perform the above task, while it accomplishes the above task most of the times, but also it shows time out few Times.

Comment: @AritraSarkar As far as I know, I'm afraid we can not break the two-minute limit in logic app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting me know that. I'll inform the business about the same. Also, do you think, that the above task is going to be best accomplished by Azure Data Factory?

Comment: @AritraSarkar Sorry, I don't know much about Azure Data Factory. You can create another post on Stack Overflow about Data Factory to implement this requirement.

Comment: Hi @HuryShen, I've added a new post on StackOverflow. Could you please look into this and share your comments. This would be very helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65803982/pick-up-records-from-sharepoint-list-based-on-max-value-of-created-field-using-a

Comment: @AritraSarkar I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I set the parameter at Get Items to 2000 even if I have 1069 rows for now and it worked perfectly.
[image]