# Pick up records from SharePoint List based on Max value of Created field using Azure Logic App

Tags: sql-server, azure-logic-apps

I've a SharePoint List with 652 rows. **Created** (Record Created Timestamp) and **Modified** (Record Updated Timestamp) are two inbuilt fields of the SharePoint List.

Staging all these 652 records along with the **Created** and **Modified** columns in an on-premise SQL Server Table using Azure Logic App. I've created the **Created** and **Modified** columns in SQL Serveras VARCHAR(100). Example of a **Created** column value in SQL Server table - **2021-01-15T06:43:00Z**

Now, my aim is to select **Max(Created)** and **Max(Modified)** from the SQL Server table and from the next time I would like to get values from the SharePoint if the SharePoint **Created** field is greater than SQL **Max(Created)** or SharePoint **Modified** field is greater than SQL **Max(Modified)**

Is this doable using Azure Logic App?

Any help is going to be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I know the trigger of your logic app ?

Comment: Do you mind use [When an item is created or modified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepoint/#when-an-item-is-created-or-modified) trigger of sharepoint connector ? If use this trigger, you may not need to check the created date and modified date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here provide two options for you to choose:

**1.** You can consider to use "[When an item is created or modified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepoint/#when-an-item-is-created-or-modified)" trigger of sharepoint connector in your logic app. If this trigger can meet your requirement, you do not need to check the max date of "**Created**" and "**Modified**" column.

**2.** If the trigger in option 1 can't meet your requirement, you can use a query like: `select max(created) as maxcreated from table` in "[Execute a SQL query (V2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#execute-a-sql-query-(v2))" action. Below is my logic app:

[image]

The expression in "**Initialize variable**" action is: `body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['ResultSets']?['Table1'][0]?['maxcreated']`

Run the logic app, the result shows:
[image]

Comment: Hi @HuryShen, The trigger is recurrence. Actually the source is SQL server, if any data is inserted or updated in SQL server then I would need to Insert or update that in SharePoint. That is why I'm using Recurrence to run everyday once

Comment: @AritraSarkar So does the second option help your problem ?

Comment: Thanks @HuryShen, I'm now able to initialize the maxCreated variable from SQL Server table. In the next step, I used Sharepoint Get items and in the Filter Query I used the expression: Created gt {x}maxCreated. But getting the following error: The expression \"Created gt 2021-01-15T06:42:58Z\" is not valid. I understand the error might be because the maxCreated variable is a String. How to proceed now?

Comment: @AritraSarkar I will do some test and then reply you later.

Comment: @AritraSarkar Add a pair of single quotes before/after `maxCreated`. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J74RX.png).